# How to create "spine charts"?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to create this kind of chart for my own data (also health indicators as in the example).

[image: Spine chart example]

I found that in the page were the image was included][1](http://www.aridhia.com/clinical-context-interpretation/using-data-to-improve-diabetes-care-2/) that they call this plot 'spine chart' , but, after a long search in Google, I couldn't find any other examples. Neither I could find any other names for this kind of plot.

So, any clue about how to name this chart and how to create it (preferable in R)?

Many thanks!

Comment: What do the grey bars represent? Are they confidence regions which the points are tested against? In that case, I think you could use ggplot2's geom_errorbar with a small `width` and larger `size` parameter to get the bars, assuming you have data on the confidence intervals, and the points would just be a `geom_point` with the point estimators. The vertical line can be added via `geom_[h|v]line` (depending on whether you `coord_flip()`).

Comment: @Jemus, those are not the confidence regions but the percentiles of the metric, being the red line the average and the coloured dots the value of a the given individual ('Clinic 1' in the example) in the distribution, so I guess the error bars of `ggplot2` are not suitable at all...

There is more info about how to read this charts [here](http://www.endoflifecare-intelligence.org.uk/view?rid=558) (bottom of page 1)

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @g3o2, I want it basically to compare the value obtained for an indicator (or set of indicators) of a given individual within the values of a set. Actually, I want to reproduce the example presented in the figure I posted. Additionally, you can check other examples [here](http://www.instantatlas.com/regional-health-profiling.xhtml)

Answer (score 2):

Spine charts like this can be created using the `fingertipscharts` package and the `area_profiles()` function.

Caveat: I'm not an expert in this package. I was looking for an answer to the same question.

---

Taken from the [fingertipscharts vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fingertipscharts/vignettes/quick_charts.html)

```
dfspine <- fingertips_data(DomainID = 1938133060, rank = TRUE) %>%
        filter(Timeperiod == "2016",
               Age == "All ages")
```

The argument `rank = TRUE` needs to be included as this returns a polarity field, which is needed for the spine chart.

```
p <- area_profiles(dfspine,
                   value = Value,
                   count = Count,
                   area_code = AreaCode,
                   local_area_code = "E06000020",
                   indicator = IndicatorName,
                   timeperiod = Timeperiod,
                   polarity = Polarity,
                   significance = ComparedtoEnglandvalueorpercentiles,
                   area_type = AreaType,
                   cols = "fingertips",
                   median_line_area_code = "E92000001",
                   comparator_area_code = "E12000005",
                   datatable = TRUE,
                   relative_domain_text_size = 0.75,
                   relative_text_size = 1.2,
                   bar_width = 0.68,
                   indicator_label_nudgex = -0.5)
p
```

[image: Spine charts from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fingertipscharts/vignettes/quick_charts.html]